# export to excel in vb.net is not fit to screen

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel

I am exporting a panel to excel but the problem is that the excel sheet i obtain is not fit to screen, i want the columns to adjust their width as to fit to the screen properly....any suggestion will mean a lot. 
The code is as

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Export.Click
    Try

        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=NFDC.xls")
        'Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename='" & filename & "'")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            'GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
            Panel1.RenderControl(hw)

            'Le format de base est le texte pour éviter les problèmes d'arrondis des nombres
            Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
            Response.Write(style)
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
        End Using


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. In EPPlus you can also set the column width to auto fit.

Comment: that i know, but i want to ask can we do it in this coding.

Comment: VDWWD is saying no you can't, because what you're producing is not really an Excel file and has no concept of "columns" until excel decides to read it and and try and interpret the HTML into an Excel style of doing things. If you want to control this you need to use a tool to produce a real Excel file, in actual Excel format (whether XLS or XLSX). If it was possible like this there would be no need to suggest an alternative, would there?

Comment: Ok.thanks for the suggestion.